# How to add Git Functionality to an Xcode Project

Tags: xcode, git

I have an Xcode Project which I created without support for source control. Is there a way for me to implement it now? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you create a Git repository in your project directory (using the usual Git tools), then Xcode will see it and offer source control features. You may need to close and open the project first.